# I get an error like "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll' because it does not exist."

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, powershell, error

After editing the SharePoint workflow, I am writing a code in the SharePoint online management shell to trigger the list manually.

I want to trigger the list with this code, but I keep getting an error. I've been searching for days but couldn't find a solution.

Do you have a solution/suggestion?

The code snippet is as follows:

```
# Add Wave16 references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site - required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"

# Specify tenant admin and site URL
$SiteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "HTTPS URL for your SP Online 2013 site"
$ListName = Read-Host -Prompt "List name you want to work on"
$UserName = Read-Host -Prompt "Email address for logging into that site"
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $UserName" -AsSecureString

# Bind to site collection
$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
$ClientContext.Credentials = $credentials
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

# Get List
$List = $ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ClientContext.Load($List)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
$ClientContext.Load($ListItems)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

# Create WorkflowServicesManager instance
$WorkflowServicesManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($ClientContext, $ClientContext.Web)

# Connect to WorkflowSubscriptionService
$WorkflowSubscriptionService = $WorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()

# Connect WorkflowInstanceService instance
$WorkflowInstanceService = $WorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

$ClientContext.Load($WorkflowServicesManager)
$ClientContext.Load($WorkflowSubscriptionService)
$ClientContext.Load($WorkflowInstanceService)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

# Get WorkflowAssociations with List
$WorkflowAssociations = $WorkflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($List.Id)
$ClientContext.Load($WorkflowAssociations)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

# Prepare Terminate Workflow Payload
$EmptyObject = New-Object System.Object
$Dict = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,System.Object]'

# Loop Restart Workflow
For ($j=0; $j -lt $ListItems.Count; $j++){

   $msg = [string]::Format("Restarting workflows {0} on ListItemID {1}", $WorkflowAssociations[0].Name, $ListItems[$j].Id)
   Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

   $itemWfInstances = $WorkflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($List.Id, $ListItems[$j].Id)
   $ClientContext.Load($itemWfInstances)
   $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   for ($k=0;$k -lt $itemWfInstances.Count;$k++) {

         # Terminate Workflow
         try {
               $WorkflowInstanceService.TerminateWorkflow($itemWfInstances[$k])
               $msg = "Workflow terminated on " + $ListItems[$j].Id
               $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
         } catch {
               $msg = "Error terminating workflow on " + $ListItems[$j].Id + " Details: $_"
         }
         Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
   }
   
   # Start Workflow
   try {
         $Action = $WorkflowInstanceService.StartWorkflowOnListItem($WorkflowAssociations[0], $ListItems[$j].Id, $Dict)
         $msg = "Workflow started on " + $ListItems[$j].Id
         $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   } catch {
         $msg = "Error starting workflow on " + $ListItems[$j].Id + " Details: $_"
   }
   Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly and at what line does it occur?